# Is the iPhone 6 more powerful than a 1980s era Cray supercomputer?

Tags: iphone

A friend today mentioned in conversation:

> You know that iPhone 6 you're carrying in your pocket. It has more computing power than the Cray supercomputers of the 80s.

That sounded vaguely right, but I wasn't sure.

My question is: **Is the iPhone 6 more powerful than a Cray supercomputer?**

Comment: More powerful in terms of what, GFLOPS?

Comment: I wasn't going to specify a particular metric - feel free to select the most appropriate one.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It would really depend on which end of the 1980s we choose. A [Cray 2, circa 1985](http://www.craysupercomputers.com/downloads/Cray2/Cray2_Brochure001.pdf) would be a good midline choice.

CPU speed of the Cray-2 was about 250MHz, with what we would today call 4 cores. 256Megs of memory but at 64bits per address instead of 8, or as we would call it today 2 GB of RAM. In terms of raw power it has been compared to an iPad. that's if you use a CPU benchmark.

However, supercomputers are usually optimized for parallel tasks or rather staggering amounts of input-output. It really isn't practical to say "my phone could replace supercomputer X from year Y" as they aren't capable of performing the same tasks. If we jump back a couple more generations we *can* say that an iPhone could have run the entire Apollo program assuming we hooked it up to a signal booster (and hold it the right way).

The iPhone beats the Cray hands-down in power consumption: 200 kW, 480 V 3-phase power coming in resulting in over 2000 amps internal power. Pressurized liquid cooling with an external heat exchanger the size of a car.

Looks awesome sitting in your dedicated computing center though.

Comment: You'd look silly holding up a Cray & typing with your thumbs though ;)

Comment: Todays iPhone battery life times suggests that this 480V 3-phase power supply was not a bad idea at all

Comment: Apparently Apple bought a Cray to help design the new Macintosh. Around the same time, Seymour Cray bought a new Macintosh to help him design his new Cray.

Comment: @LaconicDroid: For quite a while, I had a cutting from a UK newspaper that recorded that story – sadly, it got lost some time ago (or, at least, I've not seen it or a decade or more).

Comment: Was the "256 Megs" of memory therefore 4 gibibytes (8-bit bytes) in 256 mibi-words?  Or was it 256 mibibytes of memory in 32 mibi-words?  (Using 'word' for the 64-bit unit of addressable memory.)  Either way, in raw RAM, the iPhone 6 must be right up there with it (ahead if it was 256 MiB).

Comment: We would say it had 2GB of memory. 256M memory locations of 64 bits each, so multiply by 8. In the mid-1980s that was an absolutely staggering amount - home computers had 128kB. iPhone 6 has 1GB so it's still ahead there.

Comment: If you really want to know, port the [LINPACK benchmarks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LINPACK_benchmarks) to your phone and see where it would end up on the historical [TOP500 list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TOP500).  (As a point of reference, my desktop (not counting the graphics card) would have made the list any year before 2001.)

Comment: An iPhone 6 would indeed look awesome (surprising, at least) sitting in the middle of a dedicated computing center.

Comment: The iPhone 6 also has a massively parallel GPU which can be used for performing supercomputer-like tasks using something like OpenCL.

Comment: so how many iPhones would fit in a Cray ?

Comment: FYI: The [brochure](http://www.craysupercomputers.com/downloads/Cray2/Cray2_Brochure001.pdf) mentions the following about the memory: "It consists of up to 256 million 64-bit words". That is a total of 2GiB of memory..

Comment: This answer is poorly phrased.  It doesn't have "256Megs of memory", it has 2 GB arranged as 256M x 64 bits, just like a single modern 2GB DIMM.   Also - "2000 amps internal power"?!  Amps are _current_, not _power_!